# How can I protect fonts on a node webkit app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, url-routing, node-webkit

I would like to create a Node-Webkit app but avoid redistributing the font files. I have thought of a few approaches. I am considering the model used by hosted font solutions where a temporary URL containing the font file is hosted.

I have a way to encrypt the font file. You could convert the font to base64 assign it to a local variable in a javascript library with closure. The javascript file is compiled to binary and cannot be read by the end user.

Setting the base64 value to a style property would potentially expose the font as a base64 value to the DOM. What I would like to do is create a temporary route to the font file that I render from the private base64 value then remove the route once it is accessed. I can see how to achieve this as a node.js app but I'm new to Node-Webkit and don't see any documentation on router.

It seems like the hosted font solutions allow a one-time access to the font files so users cannot download the files. So does Node-Webkit have the capability to perform routing?

Comment: node-webkit (well, now officially NW.js) has access to any node.js module. Therefore, Express might work. I'm not sure, but you could do something similar to this: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: Great! So if I can use express in NW.js, I can then read the binary version of the font file with a private variable and create a one time res.render(font_file) that the app will read once. Another approach, since I'm using angularJS might be creating the route via angular to the font_file. This could be a useful approach for protecting fonts!

Answer (score 2):

First things first: welcome to the internet, you can't prevent people from using the data you send them. Either you don't send them data, or you accept the fact that once the data is on their computer, they can do with it whatever they like (if you want people to be able to connect to your content through a browser, the browser needs to download and decode the content, which means that you *cannot* stop distribution, and in fact **you** are a distributor in this scenario).

Even if you tie the font loading to a session identifier (e.g. your user has to hit the page URL first, which sets a cookie value, which is then checked when they try to download the webfont in combination with the IP for which the cookie was initially set) they only need to download your font *once* to trivially have access to it and do with it what they want. It'll either live in their browser's cache directory, or it's accessible via JavaScript (by mining `document.stylesheets` for instance) which means it's trivially converted to real data and saved to disk (e.g. a window.open with a binary mimetype causes browsers to pop up a save-to-file dialog).

There, I just downloaded your fonts despite your best efforts: if you can send me the data, and the technology we've chosen for that exchange is HTTP(S), I will be able to access that data, no matter how much you further restrict *how* or *when* I can get that data. I just need to get it once.

So: don't focus your efforts on the how or when. Take the given that your users *will* have access to your font(s), even if only once, and instead focus your efforts on what they can do with your font(s) once they do, because that's far more important. There are several things you can do to make sure that what you distribute is mostly useless outside your content. For instance:

1. Don't use full fonts, use subsets, so that your users only get partial fonts containing strictly those glyphs that are needed to render your own content. This severely limits what others can do. You can take this as far as you like, serving dedicated subset fonts per page, or even per section of a page.
2. Set the `fsType` flag for your font(s) to not allow installation. That way people will get your font(s), but they can't further use them except on the web
3. Make sure to properly mark the font(s) license in the font itself, so that if people *do* use your fonts, you have legal recourse and can sue them for circumventing your license outside the "personal use" context.

However, if you also want to take advantage of caching, you don't want to do (1), and (2) and (3) are enough to give you a legal basis to go after people who use your font(s).

Bottom line: preventing users from "getting" your data is a waste of time. It's the internet, your users getting your data is entirely the point of the technology. Instead focus on making sure that what they get is useful only within the context of your content.

After all, if TypeKit can make this work, so can you. (Which would be an additional recommendation: don't roll your own solution if you can make use of an established existing solution. Are the fonts available through Typekit or the like? Use them instead and save yourself the trouble of reinventing the wheel)

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt it and then decrypt it with node native methods for that matter:
http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

Also you can zip all your assets into one file and rename it to "package.nw" and the chrome executable will run it (I know this is not a reliable security measure) plus with that file you are able also to merge it with the nw.exe file there you'll end up with only one file that is the executable, so the regular users will not be able to see your files and your package.json file is somehow protected thus preventing users from changing the configuration and seeing your files/assets.
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#step-2a-put-your-app-with-nw-executable